# sum column with linq to sql

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a DataView in which I would like to sum a column called "Amount"

Now I know I can iterate thru the columns and get the sum but I was wondering if is possible using Linq to Sql?

String sum = Linq to Sql stuff here (doesn't have to be a string, can be any type)

Thanks,
rodchar

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Assuming the Amount column is a double (could be another type)

```
double sum = Table.Select(t => t.Amount ?? 0).Sum();
```

Or

```
double sum = Table.Sum(t => t.Amount ?? 0).Sum();
```

Using the null coelescing operator will give you a default of 0 if t.Amount is null.

Comment: This is what I had to do to get it to work: MyDataView.Table.Select().Select((t => Convert.ToDouble(t["amount"]))).Sum().ToString("c"); What if the amount is null? Would this be concern?

Answer (score 0):

we can do this using the entity framework `var sum=dbcontext.table.select(a=>a.columnname).Sum();`

Answer (score -2):

Excuse me for dataContext call syntax...

```
var sum = dataContext.Sum(x => x.Amount);
```

If you want to sum strings, you may want to use

```
var sum = string.Join(", ", dataContext.Select(x => x.StringColumn).ToArray());
```

Hope this works.