# Sum database column entries in c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL and databases. I have a table in SQL Server. In that table there is a column `price`. I want to sum all the price. What I tried is :

```
var totalAmount = db.Orders.Select(p => new { sum += p.Price });
```

What I am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try doing a .Sum like below:

```
var totalAmount = db.Orders.Select(p => p.Price ?? 0).Sum();
```

Similiar question at [sum column with linq to sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744673/sum-column-with-linq-to-sql)

Comment: +1 for catching a possible null result with the null-coalescing operator. Well done, sir. Well done indeed.

Answer (score 1):

```
var totalAmount = db.Orders.Sum(p => p.Price);
```

Answer (score 1):

you should be using `SUM` (*LiNQ Extension Method*)

```
int total = db.Orders.Sum(p => p.Price);
```

Comment: How do you know that Price is int :)

Comment: @HamletHakobyan idk, I used `int` because I assumed it as `Int`. the op is free to change it :D